# Change pytorch tensor dimension

Tags: pytorch

I have a PyTorch tensor as (2,3,4) dimension I want to make this tensor like (3,2,4) dimension. But I want a value of (:,0,:) equal to (0,:,:). I tried torch.reshape and torch.view but I cannot get the expected result.

How can I do it in PyTorch?

Comment: [`torch.permute()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.permute.html) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import torch

x = torch.randn(2, 0, 4)
print(x.shape)

x = x.permute(1, 0, 2)
print(x.shape)
```